# Receiving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined and TypeError $(...).daterangepicker is not a function Webpack Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I added the daterangepicker package with yarn to my rails 6 project with webpacker as the dependency management system for JS. The issue I am having is that jQuery itself works and is defined. But, daterangepicker is not being initialized correctly. How can I get daterangepicker to work correctly with webpacker?

application.js

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import {} from 'jquery-ujs'
import "./semantic.min"
.....
...
import moment from 'moment';
window.moment = moment;

require("daterangepicker");
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
```

environment.js

```
const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provider',
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  moment: 'moment'
  })
);
module.exports = environment;
```